# How to fix error c3848 or c2676 in c++ for this easy code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, hash, error-code

I am a beginner of C++, and I code what The Cherno teaches in [his 100th video](https://youtu.be/KiB0vRi2wlc) of the C++ series, [showing at 16:50](https://youtu.be/KiB0vRi2wlc?start=1010). But VS is always giving me error.

If without commenting the `const` part, VS gives me error c3848.  After adding `const`, VS give me error c2676.

I have checked the way to use `std::hash` on cppreference, and searched for the error on Google, but get nothing. It's just "a little bit" too hard for a beginner like me.

Below is the code.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<map> 
#include<unordered_map>

struct CityRecord
{
    std::string Name;
    uint64_t Population;
    double Latitude, Longtitude;
};

namespace std {

    template<>
    struct hash<CityRecord>
    {
        size_t operator()(const CityRecord& key) //const noexcept
        {
            return hash<std::string>()(key.Name);
        }

    };
}

int main()
{

    std::unordered_map<CityRecord, uint32_t> foundedMap;


    foundedMap[CityRecord{ "London", 500000, 2.4, 9.4 }] = 1850;


    uint32_t NewYorkYear = foundedMap[CityRecord{ "NY", 7000000, 2.4, 9.4 }];
}
```

As a beginner, I just want to know how to use the hash function in this case.

Comment: Please give the actual error messages instead of error codes, so that people don't have to look them up.

Comment: Sorry to that, but each error is far longer than code itself, so I "forget" them when I submit the problem

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, you can mark the reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the overloaded `operator()` for the specialization of `hash` for `CityRecord` a **const member function** as shown below. Additionally, we also need to overload `operator==` for `CityRecord` as shown below:

```
struct CityRecord
{
    std::string Name;
    uint64_t Population;
    double Latitude, Longtitude;
    //friend declaration for operator== not needed since we've a struct
    
};

//implement operator== 
bool operator==(const CityRecord &lhs, const CityRecord &rhs)
{
    return (lhs.Name == rhs.Name) && (lhs.Population == rhs.Population) && (lhs.Latitude ==rhs.Latitude) && (lhs.Longtitude == rhs.Longtitude);
}
namespace std {

    template<>
    struct hash<CityRecord>
    {
//-----------------------------------------------vvvvv-->added this const
        size_t operator()(const CityRecord& key) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>()(key.Name) ^ hash<uint64_t>()(key.Population) ^ hash<double>()(key.Latitude) ^ hash<double>()(key.Longtitude);
        }

    };
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/VNL0DW2Mh)

Here we use an (unnamed) `hash<string>` object to generate a hash
code for `Name`, an object of type `hash<uint64_t>` to generate a hash from `Population`, and an object of type hash to generate a hash from `Latitute` and finally an object of type `hash<double>` to generate a hash from `Longitute`. Next, we [exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) these results to form an overall hash code for the given `CityRecord` object.

Note that we defined our hash function to hash all the four data members so that our hash function will be compatible with our definition of operator== for `CityRecord`.

Comment: `operator==` can be a member of `CityRecord` instead of a non-member `friend`. But either way, its implementation can be greatly simplified using [`std::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Agreed that `operator==` can be a member. I just prefer to write it as a non-member `friend` instead. Also, since OP uses a `struct` there is no need for a friend declaration which i have mentioned in my answer. And finally yes, `std::tie` is also an option. I am just showing basic usage.

Comment: thanks for your help. it's very easy to understand for beginner. I think this is the best way to encourage beginner who crashed last night.

Comment: hey, could you please explain details about the last return hash part? I know every character, but have no idea what is the propose of this part. Because I find code runs while just hash Name :hash<std::string>()(key.Name). Thanks

Comment: @ShawnLiu We defined our hash function to hash all the four data members so that our hash function will be compatible with our definition of operator== for `CityRecord`. I have added some more explanation about the `return` hash part that you're asking at the end of my answer. Check out my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier solution, without opening the `std` namespace and specializing the `std::hash`

If you look at the definition of the `std::unordered_map` in the CPP reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), then you will read:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

It is clear and normal, to hand in template parameters for the key-type and the value-type value. However, if the key-type if a custom type, like in your case, then you need to add additional functionality.

First, you need to add `hash` functionionality. If you read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) about std::hash, then the only function the will be called is the "function call operator".

And this must be a "const" function, which will fix one of your problems.

And of course, you may add this function to your struct. That is completely OK. Please see in the example code below. With taht, you can give your own class as a template parameter for the hash functionality to the `std::unordered_map`. Cool.

If we look at the next template parameter of the `std::unordered_map`, then we will find `std::equal_to`. And if we read about [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) in cppreference, then we will find the following statement:

> Function object for performing comparisons. Unless specialised, invokes operator== on type T.

So, we need to add a comparison `operator ==` to your custom struct to satisfy requirements.

Please note: It is a good approach to encapsulate the methods operating on the data of classes within the class and not define them as free functions. Because only the methods of the class should work on the data of the class. If you would later change something in a class and have a free function doing work on the class members. So, please try to follow that approach.

Then, next, the comparison. So, we define the "operator ==" in your class and then have to compare element by element.

For easing up this task, there is a library function called `std::tie`. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie). This basically creates a `std::tuple` from the given parameters with the advantage, that all [comparison functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) are already defined and can be immediately reused.

By following the above described approach, the whole implementation will be much simpler.

Please see the below example code:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<map> 
#include<unordered_map>
#include<tuple>

struct CityRecord
{
    std::string Name;
    uint64_t Population;
    double Latitude, Longtitude;

    // For std::equal_to
    bool operator == (const CityRecord& cr) const { return std::tie(Name, Population, Latitude, Longtitude) == std::tie(cr.Name, cr.Population, cr.Latitude, cr.Longtitude); }
    // For hashing
    size_t operator()(const CityRecord& key) const { return std::hash<std::string>{}(key.Name); }
};

int main() {

    // Definition of the unordered_map
    std::unordered_map<CityRecord, uint32_t, CityRecord> foundedMap;

    // Adding data
    foundedMap[CityRecord{ "London", 500000, 2.4, 9.4 }] = 1850;
    uint32_t NewYorkYear = foundedMap[CityRecord{ "NY", 7000000, 2.4, 9.4 }];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, your answer is very sweet and carefully. For save the beginner, the first answer is better. But after that, I can learn some grace, some real skills from your code now.